# Fix position of menu bar to the left of the page

Tags: html, css, iframe, positioning

I have an HTML file which describes a menu bar. The menubar has the following format, which I import as iframe to other HTML files:

```
<ul> class="navbar">
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>  
</ul>
```

(with more li and with correct syntax, of course :) )

I have the following CSS for this:

```
ul.navbar, iframe {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 9em 
}
```

So, when I click on a link from the menu bar, the menubar shifts a little more right. Why does this happen? :/

Comment: setup an example http://jsfiddle.net that replicates the issue so we can see it

Comment: why do you add iframe to the style? makes no sense to me

Comment: What is a good alternative? Its not homework but I cant use server side like php

Comment: Extra hint: This weird behavior appears only when I use iframe. If I copy-apaste the code to every page it seems fine

Comment: Can I do something similar with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question does not supply a jsFiddle, and is unclear about the context you are using this in, I will be only guessing here.

The most likely cause of the menubar in an iframe shifting to the right after user interaction is **because of the iframe's ability to scroll**. The solution might be to set `overflow: hidden;` to the iframe and set the following style to all elements within the iframe, thus not as a style on the iframe itself. Something like: `*{margin: 0px;padding: 0px;} html,body{width: 100%;height: 100%;}` will do fine.

Please be a bit more specific about your situation. What exactly is the HTML content of the iframe and what is the context of the iframe including all CSS information. Then put it in jsFiddle or in formatted code.

Probably your problem has something to do with the iframe scrolling when focussed.